# Flutter how to fill gredient color for raised button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to render gradient button but on some device, gradient colors are not expanded like image below.

[image]

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

**Code**

```
class GradientButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  const GradientButton({@required this.child, @required this.onPressed});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      textColor: Colors.white,
      shape: StadiumBorder(),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: <Color>[Color(0xff00F260), Color(0xff0575E6)],
          ),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: child
        onPressed: onPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class GradientButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const GradientButton({Key key, this.onPressed, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        shape: const StadiumBorder(),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xff00F260), Color(0xff0575E6)],
        ),
      ),
      child: MaterialButton(
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        shape: const StadiumBorder(),
        child: child,
        onPressed: onPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You also get some `MaterialButton` effects like **Ripple** on tap, **Disabled** when onPressed is null, etc. For the elevation set `shadows` property in `ShapeDecoration`

```
shadows: [
  BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black54,
      spreadRadius: 0.5,
      blurRadius: 3,
      offset: Offset(1, 1))
]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the RaisedButton Widget and it's behaviour you can do this:

```
RaisedButton(
  textColor: Colors.white,
  shape: StadiumBorder(),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      shape: StadiumBorder(),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: <Color>[Color(0xff00F260), Color(0xff0575E6)]
      ),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(19.0,12.0,19.0,12.0),
    child: child,
  ),
  onPressed: onPressed,
),
```

But the padding around the container feels a bit like cheating.
You could just wrap a container with a GestureDetector and then manipulate the container to your needs, like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: onPressed,
  child: Container(
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      shape: StadiumBorder(),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: <Color>[Color(0xff00F260), Color(0xff0575E6)]
      ),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(19.0,12.0,19.0,12.0),
    child: Text('Lets Go',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you share the code of conainer version?

Comment: @KodaiTakata I've added the code you asked to my original response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, material button with circular border

```
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Ink(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(DEFAULT_PADDING),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        colors: <Color>[
          SECONDARY_COLOR_SHADE_DARK_NEW,
          SECONDARY_COLOR_SHADE_LITE_NEW,
        ],
      ),
  ),
    child: Text(
      buttonText,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ),
  shape: CircleBorder(),
);
```